# is It same mean "JAVA_ARGS" and "JAVA OPTS"

Tags: jvm-arguments

I want to configure java PermGen option for jenkins.

in search web, I found article which write:

```
set java_opts JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

other article says:

```
set java args JAVA_ARGS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

Are each options valid? if not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is important is what the actual arguments are in the [`"-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m"`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

What you call the environment variables is up to you for the most part, it is whatever the scripts you want to use it are expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Java applications are usually called by a startup script with a command like `java $JAVA_ARGS $JAVA_OPTS -jar application.jar`

Both variables are JVM options and they're both given to the application.

It is (unfortunately) not uncommon to have a list of 10 general options + 10 optimizations options so they're split across 2 variables for readability.

PermGen settings are considered garbage collector optimizations. They go in JAVA_OPTS. You should check that the jenkins script is using both variables as expected.